# Magento2 REST API with AngularJS and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, rest, ionic-framework, magento2

I am working on a project with Ionic, Firebase, AngularJS and trying to retrieve data from a magento2 project, locally hosted using apache2 (`http://localhost/magento2/`) in ubuntu 14.04.

I solved CORS errors adding this to my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"

</IfModule>
```

AngularJS product.js file used to retrieve a item

```
function getProducts() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/products/24-MB01',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer vbasmelg29r94nf8u10o6b8cxoko5rn9'
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log('[HTTP GET SUCCESS]', response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log('[HTTP GET ERROR]', response);
  });
}
```

I tested these HTTP calls using Postman and returned status 200 OK. When I try to use through angular I faced a output from chrome:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/products/24-MB01 ionic.bundle.js:25000
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/products/24-MB01. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400 :8100/#/product:1
```

Please, could you help me?

Comment: Hello, how did you solve the issue? I have given you up vote for the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Chrome to test your angular application, older versions (around 51.x) had these issues with preflight requests. Upgrading should get rid of the issue.